# How can one find old archived issues of LEGO Mania Magazine?

Tags: lego-group

Do any libraries contain old archived issues of them? Preferably ones on the WorldCat system?

I'm not sure if my limited storage space can handle more LEGO Mania magazines, so I'd prefer a format that's either digital or that one can easily check out from a library.

Answer (score 4):

There is currently one public library in the WorldCat system that has cataloged [LEGO Mania Magazine](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/41416761), but it does not have it available in digital form.

Other LEGO Club magazine titles have been collected by some WorldCat system libraries, including:

[Brickmaster Magazine](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/427385135)

[LEGO Club Magazine](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/229891674)

[LEGO Magazine](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/54885840)

None of these titles appear to be available in digital format from any WorldCat libraries at this time.

Comment: The LEGO Group have now started posting the latest issues of LEGO Club and LEGO Club Jr online, with the competition and member photos removed.